A geometry problem regarding the relationship between the circumradius and the radii of three other triangles
I came across this problem in my geometry book and still cannot find the solution. I am strugling with it for over a week now and I kind of ran out of ideas how to approach it. So some hints would be really appreciated.
The problem states:

Three tangents parallel to the sides of the triangle are drawn to the circle inscribed in the triangle. These tangents cut off three triangles from the given triangle, the radii of the circumscribed circles of which are equal to $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$. Express the radius of the circumscribed circle of the given triangle in terms of $R_1$, $R_2$, and $R_3$.



Hint 1) Forget about the circumsscribed circles for now, that is a bit of a false lead.
Hint 2) Try to find some connection/relation between the small triangles and the original $ABC$ one. Doing a precise drawing on an "empty" sheet of paper may help to reveal something.

The small triangles are all similar to the large one. You may wish to compute the similarity ratios (what are the scales of each of the small triangles relative to the big one).

Thank you so much, I will try to use that

Do not use phrases like "weird", or "crazy", or "no clue" in the title.

Imho there's nothing wrong with putting "weird" in the tittle. It's succinct and gets the point across, if rather generic.

Sorry, i just didn't come up with anything more appropriate.

@Dmitro, you could use "intriguing", "challenging". For many people, "weird" is not part of their vocabulary and hence not part of the "scientific" vocabulary.

Dear @Dmitro , I posted a solution but maybe I shouldn't have because it seems your post lacks enough work and attempts made by yourself. However, I consider your drawn picture as an effort. Moreover, I changed the title so that other users are less likely to vote to close your question. Please be aware that to get a good amount of attention on this website you need to show your own efforts and ideas even if they are incomplete or wrong. Otherwise, your posts are likely to get closed. I hope it helps.

@RezaRajaei, thank you a lot for help. Im just pretty new on this website, and not quite aware of how this all works here, ill try to be more careful next time. I actually just finally solved this problem myself, and then went here to check the comments and see your answer, thanks!

@Dmitro Glad I could help. That's great. If your solution is different from mine you can add it to your own question, and if it's similar to mine, you can simply accept my answer. In this way, you will show to the future readers that you are finished with your question and you also help your own post get improved. Good luck!

Let's assume $A'A''=A''T=x$ and $B'B''=B''T=y,$ where $T$ is the point of tangency.
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ 
I leave it to you to verify that:
$$\frac{R_3}{r_O}=\frac{x+y}{c}=\frac{\frac{a+b-c}{2}-x}{b}=\frac{\frac{a+b-c}{2}-y}{a}.$$
Hence,
$$\frac{R_3}{r_O}=\frac{(x+y)+(\frac{a+b-c}{2}-x)+(\frac{a+b-c}{2}-y)}{a+b+c}=\frac{a+b-c}{a+b+c}.$$
Similarly, we have:
$$\frac{R_2}{r_O}=\frac{a+c-b}{a+b+c}, \\ \frac{R_1}{r_O}=\frac{b+c-a}{a+b+c}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{R_1}{r_O}+\frac{R_2}{r_O}+\frac{R_3}{r_O}=1 \implies r_O=R_1+R_2+R_3.$$
